# Simple Quiz System in PHP MySQL - Correct & Selected Option

Tags: php

I am creating a simple quiz system (MCQ based) with the following DB Structure

id ---
name (questions) ---
options (serialize) ---
answer (0,1,2,3) --- 
cat_id (question category) ---
description

```
$catid = base64_decode($_REQUEST['test_id']);
$questions = aGetQuestionsbyCAT($catid);
shuffle($questions);
$i = 1;
foreach($questions as $ok1){
    echo "Q". $i .". ". $ok1['name'];
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$ok1['id']."' name='QId[$i]' readonly='readonly'> ";
    echo "<br />";
    $option = unserialize($ok1['option']);

    foreach($option as $ok2 => $value){
        echo "<ul style='list-style:none'><li><input type='radio' name='".$i."' value='".$ok2."' required='required'> " . $value ."</li></ul>";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

In the above codebase, my problem is I can either send the `value` or the `option id` but I want to send both.

```
foreach($option as $ok2 => $value){
        echo "<ul style='list-style:none'><li><input type='radio' name='".$i."' value='".$ok2."' required='required'> " . $value ."</li></ul>";
    }
```

As comparing `value` *(mostly which is a string with some spaces etc)* to check if the answer is correct is not very accurate and if I am not sending the `value` I will not be able to show the users what answer they selected during the test.

I have tried using `<input type='hidden' value='$value'>` in the `foreach` loop however it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: _“and if I am not sending the value I will not be able to show the users what answer they selected during the test”_ - why not? You _have_ the answer id, so you should be able to go look up the answer text using that.

Comment: Thanks man that gave me correct direction. 

Used the index of the unserialized option to fetch back the value of the options. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concate value and option_id and then add to `<input>` and then **explode** it on php code

```
foreach($option as $ok2 => $value){
        echo "<ul style='list-style:none'><li><input type='radio' name='".$i."' value='".$ok2.'~'.$value."' required='required'> " . $value ."</li></ul>";
    }
```